# How can I stop Microsoft Word from automaticaly launching and crashing? Outlook related?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook-2003

XP Pro SP 3 - Microsoft Office 2003

Recently Firefox, my browser, once again updated. Every time this happens, the rest of my programs go wonky for a few days. I suspect that Firefox has caused this problem somehow.

This time, for some reason, when I have Outlook open (basically always), Word suddenly launches for no apparent reason, and then crashes, multiple times. I can still send email, but sometimes have to open and close a message window a few times before it works.

I tried the repair tool in the Help section, but I have an OEM install and do not have the disk.

I have rebooted about 10 times and it still happens.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off Microsoft Word as the default editor for Outlook.  Instructions are listed [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-word-on-or-off-as-your-e-mail-editor-or-viewer-HP005242849.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This has had the added benefit of having my email launch more quickly.